# weather forecast data: how to know what to choose

Tags: weather-forecasting, open-data

I am interested in weather predictions at 1-day, 1-week and 2-weeks, ideally with a 1-kilometer resolution in various regions around the globe. I am particularly interested in wind speed at 100m.

I am extremely confused on how to choose the best data source for this. Some wild internet browsing presented me several NASA, ECMWF, ... forecasts that are available.

Does anyone know a comprehensive list of all the (possibly free) datasets out there for this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you looking for weather forecasts or weather model predictions? I generally define forecasts as being human generated, while predictions are weather model guidance.

Comment: Forecasts for what purpose and what area? Please [edit] your question

Comment: @shamalaia consider that models run at 1-km are for a small area of interest and a short time period; it is a very large computational burden.  If you want to use 36-12 km, there is a nice list of models with 7-day forecasts.  Global models are coarse, so location dictates which finer resolution models you can use.

Comment: I am aware of that. That is why I said "ideally". To which list are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

No agency is running 1-km forecasts globally... and certainly not out 14 days.  The only 1-km forecasts I have heard of are for small regions and just 2 days. If you can live with coarser data, [Weather.us](https://weather.us/model-charts) has a nice list of available global forecast models out there (below), and they also have a list of regional forecast models.

**Global Forecast Models:**

- ECMWF HRES (~ 9 km; 10 days)
- ECMWF EPS (~14 km; 10 days)
- ICON (~13 km; 7 days)
- GFS (~23 km; 15 days)
- GEFS (~46 km; 15 days)
- UKMO (~17 km; 6 days)
- GEM (~22 km; 10 days)
- ACCESS-G (~27 km; 10 days)
- ARPEGE (~46 km; 5 days)
- CMA (~23 km; 10 days)
- GDAPS/UM (~10 km; 12 days)